# How to save streaming aggregation in Complete output mode to Parquet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I have applied aggregation on streaming dataframe using complete mode. To save dataframe in local, I have implemented `foreach` sink. I am able to save dataframe in text form. But I need to save it in Parquet format.

```
val writerForText = new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    var fileWriter: FileWriter = _

    override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
      fileWriter.append(value.toSeq.mkString(","))
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
      fileWriter.close()
    }

    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File(s"src/test/resources/${partitionId}"))
      fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(s"src/test/resources/${partitionId}/temp"))
      true

    }
  }

val columnName = "col1"
frame.select(count(columnName),count(columnName),min(columnName),mean(columnName),max(columnName),first(columnName), last(columnName), sum(columnName))
              .writeStream.outputMode(OutputMode.Complete()).foreach(writerForText).start()
```

How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you found a way to save to parquet in complete/update mode?

Comment: Yes, i have written custom writer using https://github.com/chtefi/parquet-custom-reader-writer

Answer (score 0):

> To save dataframe in local, i have implemented foreach sink. I am able to save dataframe in text form. But i need to save it in parquet format.

The default format when saving a streaming Dataset is...**parquet**. With that said, you don't have to use a fairly advanced `foreach` sink, but merely `parquet`.

The query could be as follows:

```
scala> :type in
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> in.isStreaming
res0: Boolean = true

in.writeStream.
  option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint-so").
  start("/tmp/parquets")
```

Comment: Structured Streaming does not allow us to write dataframe to any sink in complete mode except memory. To save it, we have to implement foreach sink.  We cannot do this in complete mode which you have suggested.

Comment: Ouch...you may be right...been too much in a hurry to answer this. Let me think about it...

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal As your sink is a file it makes sense to use the **File Sink** with the append mode as in Jacek's answer. 
Your solution with the Foreach Sink seems to be overthought

Comment: I have a requirement to compute it in complete mode and save it in overwrite mode.

Comment: You'd get an IllegalArgumentException saying "Data source parquet does not support Complete output mode" if you tried executing this.